# why am i getting error in Java Type Casting

Tags: java

Why am i getting error in this statemnt.

```
byte a = 10;
byte b = +a; //Possible lossy converstion from int to byte.
```

But i'm not getting error in this statement.

```
byte a = (int)10;
```

Comment: If you make `a` `final`, the error will go away. That means `a` becomes a compile-time constant, just like `10`.

Comment: `10` is a constant, and constants can be narrowed by the compiler without a warning, if the value fits ([JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)). `+a` is a runtime expression, and runtime values cannot be narrowed by the compiler, it requires a cast.

Comment: Specifically read the section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51632153/139985 about *"Possible lossy conversion" with literals*.

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to know already, `+a` undergoes unary numeric promotion, and is of type `int`. Otherwise you wouldn't be comparing this with `byte a = (int)10;`.

The difference is that `(int)10` is a constant expression. As you have learned from your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445385/how-compile-time-constant-will-work-internally-in-java), constant expressions, if in the range of the target primitive type, can be implicitly converted to that type without a cast. Well, according the language specification [$15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), `(int)10` is a constant expression!

Here's what the spec says:

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive
>   type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
>   only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type String (§15.16)
> - The unary operators +, -, ~, and ! (but not ++ or --) (§15.15.3, §15.15.4, §15.15.5, §15.15.6)
> - The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
> - The additive operators + and - (§15.18)
> - ...

For `(int)10`, `10` is a constant expression, and `(int)10` is a cast to a primitive type, so the whole expression is a constant expression.

`+a` is not a constant expression because it involves the non-final variable `a`.